# PowerPoint VBA Event Handler

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am currently working on a macro that automatically imports images, charts,... into PowerPoint using VBA. To do so the file name of the image/chart that needs to be put on the slide is written in the placeholder as

```
<filename.png>
```

Whenever this text is changed by the user I want an event to be triggered that checks if the image with this name exists. If not I want to give out an error.

Now I have a problem with the events I use. I am currently using

```
WindowSelectionChange
```

which activates whenever I select anything on the slide. But after clicking on a placeholder containing the <...> the event is always triggered several times (at least 4 times) and I only wanted it to be triggered when the text in the placeholder is changed.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: One thought:  in your event handler, check to see if the name or id of the currently selected shape is the same as one stored in a global or static variable; if so, exit sub ... don't respond to the selection change. Otherwise store the name of the new selection and respond to the selection change as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, that idea helped a lot. I store the string in the placeholder elements in global variables and only check the image for availability when the string (=file name) has changed. Works great!